# C# ternary operator + convert in CHAR not working

Tags: c#, conditional-operator, ternary

I'm currently learning C#, I am a beginner, so I'm not really familiar with the particularities of this language.

My problem is:

I have this piece of code which is supposed to convert an INTEGER to a CHAR and add 55 to the INTEGER to obtain the ASCII code for the hexadecimal when the user chooses a base between 11 and 16. When I use a simple "if" and "else" it works perfectly well, but for some reason, it doesn't work with the ternary operator

---

```
nConverti += (pNewbase > 10 && n >= 10) ?( n += 55 : (char)(n)): n;

nConverti += Depiler(ref unePile);
```

---

Just for presision I'm currently using Visual Studio 2022 version 17.8.5 and the framework's version is 4.8.09032.

I thank in advance anyone who will help me resolve this issue.

I already tried to read all the documentation I found about the ternary in C# but didn't found any solution, I even asked my college teacher who wasn't able to help me too. I also tried to update my framework and my visual studio but still doesn't change (even if I don't really think that the issue comes from there).

Comment: That doesn't compile. `( n += 55 : (char)(n))` doesn't make sense where it is, what is that `:`? Why do you use `+=`?

Comment: The syntax is not valid. There is one `?` operator, but two `:`. The inner block `( n += 55 : (char)(n))` seems to be missing the condition statement.

Comment: If you had it working with an `if`-`else` syntax, just keep it. Cramping everything into one line does not award you anything and apparently just caused you to break your code. Readability suffers and it may not be you who has to understand that line in the future. (Also, please don't use the phrase "it doesn't work" - state explicitly what does not work, e.g. what error message the compiler emits, or what expected and actual results are if those are wrong.)

Comment: If you showed us the working if-else, we could help you converting it to a ternary expression or explain why it is not possible to do so. Note that the ternary expression can only contain expressions but no statements.

Answer (score 2):

The ternary operator works as follows: `condition ? [true expression] : [false expression]`

```
nConverti += (pNewbase > 10 && n >= 10) ? (char)(n + 55) : (char)n;
```

using the assignment operator `+=` inside the `ternary expression`, which is not necessary and can lead to confusion better to write in `if else` and its upto you

```
if (pNewbase > 10 && n >= 10)
{
    nConverti += (char)(n + 55);
}
else
{
    nConverti += (char)n;
}
```

Comment: Not only beginners should actually go with the rule to never use an assignment operation within a conditional expression.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with all the others that the code as written is not syntactically correct. Also a little difficult from your description to make out the intent but.
Nice to provide the Visual Studio and Framework versions but these are not all that important. Your code is just basic C# that should be compatible with all current versions of the language.

```
int n = 11;
int newBase = 10;
string converti = "";
converti += (newBase > 10 && n >= 10) ? (char)(n + 55) : (char)n;
```

Above is what I think you are trying to do.
A few things to note.
The code that you have include has this phrase `( n += 55 : (char)(n))` but this is not a syntactically correct.
I've replaced this with `(char)(n + 55)`

It's important to note that both values returned by the ternary operator must be the same type that is the result of a single expression.

If we have misinterpreted your code, please add a little more context and also show the version of the code that is written using the `if` statement.